# How to use pinch to rotate using keyboard/mouse (without trackpad)?

Tags: keyboard, preview, multi-touch

I'm trying to rotate texts and images in Preview without using the multitouch 'rotate with two fingers'. It works fine with a laptop trackpad but on a desktop with only a keyboard and mouse I can't find a way to rotate things.

edit: I'm using the LogitechMX Master, but what I was hoping there was a solution just using right/left click and the keyboard, or some setting in Preview. Basically any way of doing it that doesn't require the use of the trackpad.

edit2: Specifically, I want to rotate elements inside of the image, such as text.

[image: ex1]

I believe that any solution, if it exists, should not be particular to Preview but instead some way of doing the "rotate with two fingers" trackpad gesture, without a trackpad.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to our site. :) Can I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/418022/edit) your question to clarify what mouse you're using? Otherwise we have no way of knowing if what you want is possible, let alone advise *how* to do what you want.